# Code-First Entity Class Creation Skips Table , Should I redesign

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

The below database schema was created by reading an xml file in to a data set and then translating the tables and relations into a SQL Server database.

- foreach table in dataset,

  - create a table,

    - for each relation in the dataset
    - create relations.

The class files were generated via Entity Framework; Visual Studio 2015, Add ADO Item, code-first from database.

As you will note the `Component` table is completely ignored by Entity Framework class file generation. See my summarized questions..

I ran `XSD.exe /c` on my xsd file and it created the `Component` class.

Given the tables and relations were created via xml to dataset to SQL Server - and not designed manually;

- Should this E-R model be changed ?
- Should I create 2 separate tables for `Component` such as `AssemblyItemA_Component` and then `AssemblyItemB_Component` ?

I will be processing XML files that follow this pattern and adding their data to these tables, so it is important to know what I should do here ?

I am thinking I should further normalize the tables into two tables, any suggestions are appreciated.

Upon processing XML files once they are in SQL Server; I will be performing a couple different functions and processes and then transferring a units_Id associated records to a work_Table and then updating the original tables from the work_Table as needed.

In summary:

- Why did Entity Framework class file generation completely ignore the `Component` table?
- Should I redesign the E-R structure for the `Component` table?
- If re-design: should I create 2 separate tables `AssemblyItemA_Component` and `AssemblyItemB_Component` [Ease of querying would be better?]
- I will mainly be updating the Units , Unit and the AssemblyItemA/B tables (query to include `Component`). I would like to have a sample EF framework for query / (insert or update).

**EDIT**

From comments EF needs a primary key. Got it..

> Now should I redesign the table structure manually; there are many
>   ways to do it what is best or good practice given the data?

- Split Components into two tables CompA, CompB.
- Add Id field and get rid of FK Constraints.
- Add PartType and PartCode to the AssemblyItemA and AssemblyItemB tables?
- Where should I do this change first in Dataset from XML file and then let it generate tables for SQL and handle everything that way ?

SQL scripts for creating the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssemblyItemA]
(
    [AssemblyItemA_Id][int]NOT NULL,
    [Unit_Id] [int]NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AssemblyItemA]  
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([AssemblyItemA_Id] ASC)
) ON[PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssemblyItemB]
(
    [AssemblyItemB_Id][int]NOT NULL,
    [Unit_Id] [int]NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AssemblyItemB] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([AssemblyItemB_Id] ASC)
) ON[PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Component]
(
    [PartType][varchar](255) NULL,
    [PartCode][varchar](255) NULL,
    [AssemblyItemA_Id][int]NULL,
    [AssemblyItemB_Id][int]NULL
) ON[PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Unit]
(
    [Unit_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PartCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PartType] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Units_Id] [int]NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Unit] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Unit_Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Units]
(
    [Units_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Batch_Id] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Units] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Units_Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AssemblyItemA] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Unit_AssemblyItemA] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Unit_Id]) REFERENCES[dbo].[Unit] ([Unit_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AssemblyItemA]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [Unit_AssemblyItemA]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AssemblyItemB] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Unit_AssemblyItemB] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Unit_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Unit] ([Unit_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AssemblyItemB]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [Unit_AssemblyItemB]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Component] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [AssemblyItemA_Component] 
        FOREIGN KEY([AssemblyItemA_Id]) REFERENCES[dbo].[AssemblyItemA] ([AssemblyItemA_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Component]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [AssemblyItemA_Component]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Component] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [AssemblyItemB_Component] 
        FOREIGN KEY([AssemblyItemB_Id]) REFERENCES[dbo].[AssemblyItemB] ([AssemblyItemB_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Component]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [AssemblyItemB_Component]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Unit] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Units_Unit] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Units_Id]) REFERENCES[dbo].[Units] ([Units_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Unit]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [Units_Unit]
```

Context class created by Entity Framework (code-first approach):

```
namespace MyContext
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
    using System.Linq;

    [Table("AssemblyItemB")]
    public partial class AssemblyItemB
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int AssemblyItemB_Id { get; set; }
        public int? Unit_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("AssemblyItemA")]
    public partial class AssemblyItemA
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int AssemblyItemA_Id { get; set; }
        public int? Unit_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Unit")]
    public partial class Unit
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Unit()
        {
            AssemblyItemAs = new HashSet<AssemblyItemA>();
            AssemblyItemBs = new HashSet<AssemblyItemB>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Unit_Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string UnitNumber { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string PartCode { get; set; }
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string PartType { get; set; }
        public int? Units_Id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AssemblyItemA> AssemblyItemAs { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AssemblyItemB> AssemblyItemBs { get; set; }
        public virtual Unit1 Unit1 { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Units")]
    public partial class Unit1
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Unit1()
        {
            Units = new HashSet<Unit>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Units_Id { get; set; }
        public int? Batch_Id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Unit> Units { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TESTV1Context : DbContext
    {
        public TESTV1Context() : base("name=TESTV1Context")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AssemblyItemA> AssemblyItemAs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AssemblyItemB> AssemblyItemBs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Unit1> Units1 { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the PK for the Components table? Notice it's the only table that doesn't have one

Comment: move this to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IvanStarostin That's a terrible suggestion. Please read and understand Code Review's How To Ask before suggesting that again

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you are correct I am not sure why the dataset did not create a key for that, I know that both AssemblyItemA and AssemblyItemB can have a child node called component ..perhaps there was no identifier for the dataset to be able to translate that properly ??

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Given my xml file has a child node component for assemblyA and child node component for AssemblyB (same info just different) do you think I should just manually redesign the SQL table and handle the insertion of data into my re-designed table?  Or change what I have in the dataset model that I read in xml data file so that I am consistent and then deal with sql database from there ?  I am guessing the latter is more difficult - given the same table is used for both of these ..

Answer (score 2):

EF requires all tables to have a primary key, and your Component table does not have one

Comment: ok that answers first question -thx. On to second question, Should I redesign the E-R structure for the Component table, and
If I do a manual re-design: should I create 2 separate tables AssemblyItemA_Component and AssemblyItemB_Component .? Should I do this first in the dataset I am importing the xml file into , and then handle everything afterwards ?

Comment: Or should I just get rid of the FK constraints and add an Id field to the components table ? lots of ways to redesign - I could just add PartType, PartCode to the AssemblyA/B tables